# How to return an array of indexes from the first array which is the intersection of indexes from two sorted arrays?

Tags: javascript

**I wrote a solution that allows me to get an array of indexes from the first array which is the intersection of indexes from two sorted arrays and I'd like to know why this solution is wrong. When I check it I get the correct array of indexes from the first array but the interviewer told me that this is wrong.**

***Thanks a lot for the help and explanations.*** I have no commercial experience yet. Sorry for some mistakes in English, as I am from Ukraine and I improve this language.

```
// first example of input:

// const arr1 = [1, 2, 2, 2];
// const arr2 = [1, 1, 2, 2];

// second example of input:

const arr1 = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 9, 20];
const arr2 = [1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 8, 9, 9, 21];

// first example of output:

// - [0, 1, 2]
// - [0, 1, 3]
// - [0, 2, 3]

// second example of output:

// - [0, 1, 3, 5, 8, 9]
// - [0, 2, 3, 5, 8, 9]

//function compareItemsFn, length1, length2 - from conditions to this task

const compareItemsFn = (index1, index2) => {
    switch (true) {
        case arr1[index1] === arr2[index2]: return 0;
        case arr1[index1] < arr2[index2]: return -1;
        case arr1[index1] > arr2[index2]: return 1;
        default: return undefined;
    }
};
const length1 = arr1.length;
const length2 = arr2.length;

// function intersectionIndexes - my solution

function intersectionIndexes(compareItemsFn, length1, length2) {
    let indexesIntersectionArray = [];

    let i = 0;
    let j = 0;

    while (i < length1 && j < length2) {

        if (compareItemsFn (i, j) === 0) {
            indexesIntersectionArray.push(i);
            i++;
            j++;
        } else if (compareItemsFn (i, j) === 1) {
            j++;
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }

    return indexesIntersectionArray;
};

const result = intersectionIndexes(compareItemsFn, length1, length2);
```

Comment: For starters. const compareItemsFn = (index1, index2) =\> { should be: const compareItemsFn = (index1, index2) => {

Comment: Here are some tips: 1. Remove all the backslashes. 2. Try one line at a time and test it. 3. Be clear about one input and expected output. Your question is confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are certain that your solution works then perhaps it was not wrong in the sense that it gave the wrong answer but rather in the way you solved the problem.

The following code is a simplification of your solution. It takes the two arrays as parameters instead of the value of their `length` property so the solution isn't tied to the global variables `arr1` and `arr2`. You should always favor implementing solutions that are generalised.

In place of your `compareItemsFn` function, the [Math.sign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sign) method from the standard library is used. Some times in interview situations you can be asked to implement functionality which can be found in the standard library and what the interviewer is looking to see is if you are aware of it.

```
function simplified(arrayOne, arrayTwo) {
  let result = [];
  let indexOne = 0;
  let indexTwo = 0;

  while (indexOne < arrayOne.length && indexTwo < arrayTwo.length) {
    let signCheck = Math.sign(arrayOne[indexOne] - arrayTwo[indexTwo]);
    if (signCheck == 0) {
      result.push(indexOne);
      indexOne++;
      indexTwo++;
    } 
    else if ( signCheck > 0) {
      indexTwo++;
    }
    else {
      indexOne++;
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for example and advices, but interviewer gave me only lengths of two arrays and function compareItemsFn() and arrays weren't known. I didn't specify this in the condition in my code because I ask here - in stackoverflow - for the first time. Thank you so much for your help!